# how do I use variables when binding backbone view events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, coffeescript

I want to bind an event to a view using a selector I define in the view's options.

Something like (in coffescript):

```
events: ()->
  "change" : "setNewCheckedStateWithCheckbox"
  '"click'+ @.options.choices_button_selector +'"' : "test"
```

Can't for the life of me figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you can't do expressions in the keys of JavaScript object literals. The only way to set arbitrary keys on objects it to use the `obj[expression]` syntax.

Here's one way to rewrite your code to do what you want:

```
class MyView extends Backbone.View
  _events = change: "setNewCheckedStateWithCheckbox"
  events: ->
    eventsHash = _.extend {}, _events
    eventsHash["click #{@.options.choices_button_selector}"] = "test"
    eventsHash
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks!  I ended up re factoring the whole view but this is something I come across, and wonder about quite often.  Perfect!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
events: ()->
  "change" : "setNewCheckedStateWithCheckbox"
  "click#{@options.choices_button_selector}" : "test"
```

next time just stick in a `console.log` to display values you're not sure about.

```
console.log '"click'+ @.options.choices_button_selector +'"'
```

that would output `"click#selector"` with the quotes (that shouldn't be there).

Comment: Yep, that #{} is close to what I was looking for but it throws a syntax error: Unexpected '{'

Comment: what are you using to compile?

Comment: It's a rails 3 application using barista.

Comment: well then there is another error somewhere in your code because that is valid coffeescript.

Comment: @ilia No, it's not. You can't use string interpolation in object keys. The feature was briefly supported, but it was removed before the 1.0 release.

Comment: @TrevorBurnham wow i never knew that. Learned something today.